# Microsoft Azure: How to pass an event to Azure's Event Queue upon Table Storage row insertion/deletion

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to create a system in which whenever a row is inserted/deleted in a table (Azure Table Storage), that event gets passed to a Queue. I have already created the table and created the Queue intended to store the events, however, I am having trouble figuring out how exactly to create a function in Azure that will link up the table event with the Queue. Below is my Azure dashboard:

[image]

To summarize: whenever a row is added to the table highlighted in green, that event is passed to the Queue highlighted in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a table trigger function and send the row entity to storage queue.

However, **Trigger Azure Function From Table Storage is not support now**.

You can vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/33483367-trigger-azure-function-from-table-storage) to prompt it to be achieved.